# ASP.NET Core: model invalid due to related ICollections

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

When submitting my post request, `ModelState.IsValid` is always `false` due to the related entities being empty.

```
    [Key]
    [Required()]
    public int ID {get; set;}

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required()]
    public string NAME {get; set;}

    public ICollection<ActorMovieJunction> NameJobJunction {get; set;}
```

Both the `ID` and the `NAME` show up as valid in the state model, but `NameJobJunction` being "null" creates an error.

I'm also using the `[BindProperty]` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is a new nullable feature net6. I highly recommend you to remove it or comment in project properties

```
 <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
```

Or you will have to mark all nullable properties as nullable.

```
 public ICollection<ActorMovieJunction>? NameJobJunction {get; set;}
```

and IMHO never use [Bind] in the controller action parameters.

Comment: Perfect, I previously used 3.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give a default value to `NameJobJunction`:

```
public ICollection<ActorMovieJunction> NameJobJunction {get; set;}=new List<ActorMovieJunction>();
```